# How does ReentrantLock synchronize?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, reentrantlock

I have looked at the Java API for ReentrantLock and what I can see is that no synchronization is used with the `synchronized` keyword. Is it in the below method in AbstractQueuedSynchronizer (that ReentrantLock is refering to when trying to aquire a lock) that synchronizes the object? Since the `compareAndSwapInt` is a native method, is the synchronization made at the native level/code?

```
protected final boolean compareAndSetState(int expect, int update) {
    // See below for intrinsics setup to support this
    return unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, expect, update);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation will likely be different per JDK. Sun (now Oracle) implementation, for example, does it via `sun.misc.Unsafe` ( http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html )

I once blogged about how [Java concurrency in unsafe](http://pveller.blogspot.com/2010/08/java-concurrency-is-unsafe.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct: in Oracle's JDK, `ReentrantLock` is implemented in terms of the native [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) primitive (plus a fair amount of Java code on top of it), and not in terms of the `synchronized` keyword.